# What's the difference between `myprogram` and `start /w myprogram`?

Tags: cmd

In a Batch (`cmd.exe`) script, what's the difference between running commands directly:

```
myprogram
```

and running them using `start /w`?

```
start /w myprogram
```

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198044

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198044

When you use this method (the /w), the programs in the batch file are started sequentially. The next program does not start until you quit the previous program.

Comment: I think the OP was asking how that is any different from running the commands one after the other without `start /w`.

Comment: ah yes, I see it has been edited.  In that case I don't think there is a difference.  If I remember correctly the only way I got batch files to run a bunch of programs at once was to create a perl wrapper thet then opened a new process that started the app I wanted and then the original could die while the needed app was loading.